# Displacement modifier with UV map weird results

Tags: texturing, uv, displacement, 3d-printing

Noob here. I found an obj [model with UV map and texture bundled](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/a-queen-from-the-lewis-chesspieces-e451589dbf00489eb49d60d89e6ddd34). Mesh itself is pretty low quality, but when texture is applied, it looks just great. So I tried to use supplied texture as displacement map. Using nodes I was able to get the visual effect I desire, but it is not displacing the mesh, so I cannot export and 3D print it.

[image]

Displacement modifier is doing weird things, but not even remotely near to what I need.

[image]

UVmap seems to be in place and mapping correct regions.

[image]

I have already spend a whole week trying to understand what I'm doing wrong what causes results I'm getting. Please, help me stand on the right path to solution.

[Blender file is here (iCloud)](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0b5mdaY1AiWEVd6qoiZsWZemg#ttt1-with_texture)

[Blender file is here (Google drive)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Hf4EC5et1Bz3Ev3KcjyI5JXAsZD7p0ef?usp=sharing)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: hello please pack your images before sharing, or give a link to the images

Comment: Images are in the first link
but here is the folder https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/03dhCjjYHC-b6DvT0pur9sSPg#lewisKing82

Comment: Hi :). Displacement values are in meters. Perhaps you need to scale the strength down to 0,01 or something like that.

Comment: I don't have any icloud account, it looks like I can't download, could you please use another platform?  :(

Comment: Sorry for iCloud links, here is google drive
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Hf4EC5et1Bz3Ev3KcjyI5JXAsZD7p0ef?usp=sharing

Comment: That mesh does not look low poly to me. Low poly would be like 16 vertices total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s Normal that the material does not make actual 3D changes to the mesh, and especially ones that cannot be exported. It’s meant as an effect for the render only. The displacement modifier would be the way to go, but as others have commented, turn down the strength. One last warning, however, the displacement modifier can only work with what mesh is there. To get all the detail of the displacement map, you would have to subdivide the mesh until every pixel has a corresponding vertex. This is of course impractical, so I might recommend using sculpting tools to either draw in the etches yourself, or use circle select to only subdivide the regions that absolutely need it. I recommend you create the rough stony texture in physical post as a whole with sand or a wire brush. Search around for better ways to do it than I have suggested, as I have never 3D printed before.

Comment: It's significantly better now. Thank you!