# Displacement modifier creates dotted indents for smooth lines at texture

Tags: texturing, modifiers, displacement

Following [the advice](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264870/displacement-modifier-with-uv-map-weird-results) to redraw the lines in the texture myself, I'm trying to displace a texture on a model with UV map already applied. On the texture I have hand drawn lines and expect them to be embossed on the surface of the model. Suspecting that issue is with the intensity of the colours I added some experimental lines.

[image]

But the result I'm getting from the displacement modifier consists of series of dots, not the continuous lines I expect.

Why is that?

[Google drive folder with files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mIxMn_ylrdiB5iZokqqmcCa0B3ggkWW9?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you don't have enough geometry for such a thick lines. You would have to subdivide model before Displacement.

[image]

BTW *Remesh* modifier destroys your *UV maps* (just a note if you planned to 3Dprint texture as well).

Comment: Ooo, happy day! Thank you!!!